# Unable to call static method in class from another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class file which contains a function to hash an input string.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XHD_Console
{
    public class HashingSystem
    {
        public static string Sha256(string text)
        {
            string hashString = string.Empty;
            //code for hashing here, contains some things i'd rather not release.
            return hashString;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call the sha256 function from a form, intellisense detects the class HashingSystem, but not the function. Is there a reason? I've read it needs to be static, done that but to no avail. Both classes are in the same namespace, but the class hashingsystem has it's own file, hashingsystem.cs

To call the function:

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.EnteredPassword = HashingSystem.sha256(input_Password.Text);
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: It's just a normal windows C# form, it's for password entry, thus the hash function.

Comment: make HashingSystem a public class

Comment: If both classes are not in the same Assembly(compilation unit/Visual Studio project), then make HashingSystem public.

Comment: I can access the class, just not the method inside of it.

Comment: If they really are in the same namespace and project it shouldn't matter that they are internal right.

Comment: They're both in the same project and all public. I'm simply looking to call it as if it were a normal function.

Comment: The OP is most likely creating an instance of HashingSystem instead of calling it statically

Comment: How are you calling this method ? You can't call this method on an instance of the class because the method is static.
You must call it like 'HashingSystem.sha256("bla")'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Static method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792240/calling-a-static-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just make HashingSystem class public *public class HashingSystem*

Comment: Btw, your function starts with a capital (like it should) But you call it without capital.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `static` members against the `class`, not against an *instance* of a `class`. So you need to use:

```
HashingSystem.sha256("texthere");
```

Also, consider changing:

```
class HashingSystem
```

to:

```
public class HashingSystem
```

Classes are [`internal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824555/why-visual-studio-doesnt-create-a-public-class-by-default) by default. *I would recommend you always be explicit about visibility (i.e. always specify `internal`, `public` or `private`).*

Comment: It's public static class, but calling it like `HashingSystem.sha256(string)` gives me an error; the name 'sha256' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please update your post to include the **entire method of the calling code**, and the actual `HashingSystem` class (since the `HashingSystem` class in your post is definitely **not** public). Also please include a screenshot of the compiler error you are receiving.

Comment: There's one class HashingSystem. I have tried making the class public which did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do this?

```
    HashingSystem hs = new HashingSystem();
    hs.sha256("Hello World"); //This wont work as static methods cannot be called via instances
```

Use the below way instead

```
    HashingSystem.sha256("Hello world");//Calling directly via class
```